# What is the difference between $("") and $.find("")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand the difference between `$("")` and `$.find("")`. They behave differently when nothing is matched but you try to do something with the result (like call `toggle()`).

```
$("").toggle(); // No error

$.find("").toggle(); // An error

$("body").find("").toggle(); // No error!

$($.find("")).toggle(); // No error
```

Why? :-)

In my context I have a function that uses `$` to search for elements globally and has no problems when nothing matches. Now I want to allow the function to search only inside specified element (wrapped in a jQuery object). But it still should work if I pass `$` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.find("")` returns an empty array so it throws an error when you use `[].toggle()` as array has no toggle method.

And wrapping it inside jQuery i.e. $ like `$($.find(""))` returns an empty object `Object[]` and using toggle() in jQuery object won't throw an error.

> $.find is internal CSS selector engine (Sizzle) and the function returns just and array of found elements. It's not jQuery instance and hence doesn't have jQuery prototype methods like toggle. (Thanks @dfsq)

There's no shorthand method <strike>[$.find](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.find)</strike> for [find](http://api.jquery.com/find) in jquery

Comment: This is correct answer. To add to it, `$.find` is an internal CSS selector engine (Sizzle) and the function returns just and array of found elements. It's not jQuery instance and hence doesn't have jQuery prototype methods like `toggle`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the official jQuery doc has to say about .find method:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

The difference between $.find("") and $("").find("") is:
$.find begins traversing the DOM from the very top of the DOM tree, whereas $("").find start traversing the DOM from the specified DOM element and tries to find it's children.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `toggle` is a jQuery function which is only available within a jQuery object BUT `$.find()` does not return a jQuery object instead it returns vanilla JavaScript object. Hence the error.

Whereas any jQuery selector will return a jQuery object hence, if you convert this `$.find` to jQuery object then it works.

You can try the following code to check if an object is jQuery object or not.

```
$("#mainbar") instanceof jQuery
//Output: true

$.find("#mainbar") instanceof jQuery
//Output: false

$($.find("#mainbar")) instanceof jQuery
//Output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

See official jQuery documentation, which states:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements (…)

So in other words, `.find()` only works correctly when you want to find something **inside already selected elements**.